# Browser crashed event

Tags: puppeteer

I am wondering if there is some event that is emitted when browser has crashed. I would like to start a new browser when some browser has crashed.
I am running multiple browsers (each with different proxy).

Also is there some function that will return count of open browsers (where is atleast one tab opened)?

Comment: Sorry for the earlier comment, didn't see the tag. [`disconnected` event](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#event-disconnected) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Will it provide you the reason why it has crashed? I want to know if the browser has crashed because proxy error or if it has crashed for other reason (like out of memory).